# bind angularjs currency to scaleLabel in chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, chart.js

I'm working with Angularjs and Chartjs is there a way to bind a currency to the scaleLabel. In Html I would normally do

```
{{value | currency }}
```

This is the label from chartjs graph options

```
scaleLabel: "<%= '$' + value  %>"
```

Is there a way to do this instead of having the currency hard coded please?

This is my HTML in which i'm calling controller and $scopes

```
<div ng-controller="ChartJSController" class="container-fluid">
<div class="row mb-lg">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div>
            <canvas linechart="" options="lineOptions" data="rev" height="667" responsive="true"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the graph data

```
    $scope.revenueToday = {
    labels: ['00:00', '01:00', '02:00', '03:00', '04:00', '05:00', '06:00', '07:00', '08:00'],
    datasets: [
      {
          label: 'My Second dataset',
          fillColor: 'rgba(35,183,229,0.2)',
          strokeColor: 'rgba(35,183,229,1)',
          pointColor: 'rgba(35,183,229,1)',
          pointStrokeColor: '#fff',
          pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
          pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(35,183,229,1)',
          data: log

      }
    ]
};
```

And this is where I am setting graph options

```
    $scope.lineOptions = {
    scaleShowGridLines: true,
    scaleGridLineColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,.05)',
    scaleGridLineWidth: 1,
    bezierCurve: true,
    bezierCurveTension: 0.4,
    pointDot: true,
    pointDotRadius: 4,
    pointDotStrokeWidth: 1,
    pointHitDetectionRadius: 20,
    datasetStroke: true,
    datasetStrokeWidth: 2,
    datasetFill: true,
    scaleLabel: "<%= '$' + value  %>"

};
```

Comment: Can you add some more code of controller and chartjs?

Comment: are you trying to ask how to make the output of chart.js use an angular currency filter?

Comment: Yes that's what I am asking. Currently as you can see in scaleLabel: "<%= '$' + value  %>" I used a string '$' now I'm trying to change that and use angular's currency filter

Comment: pretty sure this isn't going to be possible without hacking the source of chart.js;  those `value` are populated internally in the JavaScript and aren't exposed externally where the filter could be applied.  you can't apply the filter to a template, it has to be applied to a value, and unfortunately `scaleLabel` is using a template, in chart.js format.

Comment: Is there another way without using scaleLabel?

Comment: the problem isn't `scaleLabel`, it's the fact that what you would need to filter, `value`, isn't exposed for each plot point on the chart.  Angular can't see these distinct variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, however you'd have to tack your bit of code that does the formatting to some global object (which IMO is not very maintainable). This is how you do it

```
myApp.controller('myCtrlr', ['$filter', '$scope', function ($filter, $scope) {
    Chart.currencify = function(value) {
        return $filter('currency')(value);
    }
    ...
    ...
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, {
        scaleLabel: "<%=Chart.currencify(value)%>",
    });
}]);
```

You could tack the currencify function to any global object (I've added it to the Chart js global object). All you have to make sure is that `currencify` is defined before you initialize the chart (so you could also do it in `myApp.run`).

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/fntcdtve/

Comment: Thanks I will try that